# Get route params inside actioncreator/selector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

Using redux router, In my components I have access to the `params` object with information about by URL.

However, inside my actioncreators, I get the state through `getState()`, and thus the params props has not been injected.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Elaborating more on your specific case and providing some code could help other better help you.

Comment: State and props are different by all means. Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to get access params in action creators, you should pass it:**

in component

```
this.props.someAction(this.props.params)
```

in action creator

```
const someAction = (params)=>{
    let {data} = params;
    ....
}
```

**to get access params in selector, you should pass it:**

in component

```
const mapStateToProps=(state, ownProps)=({
  data:someSelector(state,ownProps.params)
})
```

in selector

```
const someSelector=(state, params)={
   ..some computing
   return result
}
```

**to get access from getState() to router's  params, pathname and query:**

you need to install [redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router#differences-with-react-router-redux)

if you allready using it , then check

1.routes

```
import { ReduxRouter } from 'redux-router';

<Provider store={store}>
     <ReduxRouter>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
         //...routes
            </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
</Provider>
```

2.reducer

```
import { routerStateReducer } from 'redux-router';
const reducer = combineReducers({
router: routerStateReducer,
...
});
```

3.store enchancer

```
import { reduxReactRouter} from 'redux-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
const store = compose(
  applyMiddleware(m1, m2, ...),
  reduxReactRouter({
    createHistory
  })
)(createStore)(reducer);
```